# Aggregate Command in R, Remove Columns?

Tags: r

My aggregate command takes the mean of all of my columns based on a specific variable. I would like for it to only apply the function to certain columns. I have my code in the following format for aggregate:

```
aggregate(dataframe,list(name=variable),mean)
```

This gives me the mean for my different columns based on a specific variable.I would like to selectively choose my columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply the function for select columns `2 and 3` (numeric index)

```
 aggregate(dat1[,2:3], list(name=dat1[,'variable']), FUN=mean)
 #   name   V1   V2
 #1    A 10.2 11.2
 #2    B 12.8  7.6
```

Or you could replace the numeric index with column names

```
 aggregate(dat1[,c("V1", "V2")], list(name=dat1[,'variable']), FUN=mean)
 #  name   V1   V2
 #1    A 10.2 11.2
 #2    B 12.8  7.6
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 dat1 %>%
      group_by(variable) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)), V1,V2)
 #  variable   V1   V2
 #1        A 10.2 11.2
 #2        B 12.8  7.6
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=variable, .SDcols=colnames(dat1)[2:3]]
 #  variable   V1   V2
 #1:        A 10.2 11.2
 #2:        B 12.8  7.6
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dat1 <- cbind(variable=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5),
       as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)))
```

Comment: Great! In terms of selecting columns in method one with the numeric index, what is the purpose of the comma? as in [,#:#]? Also, what if i wanted columns 3-8 but not 7?

Comment: @yearsofwisdom You don't need the comma.  It is just that I got accustomed to using `,` to separate `row` and `column` index. For the second question, you can use `c` ie. `aggregate(yourdata[,c(3:6,8)], list(name...)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining with a formula:

```
aggregate(cbind(Var2mean1, Var2mean2) ~ groupvar, data = dataframe, FUN = mean)
```